# Django make form field iterable

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Having trouble getting my view to assign a role to a user. I'm using django-roles-permissions and everything works correctly in the shell, but when I try to use forms and views I get multiple errors. I think  mostly figured it out, and I'm down to one error of: `'CharField' object is not iterable`. I tried using .split(',') but it said it has no split attribute. Here is my code:

**forms.py:**

```
ROLES = [[g.id, g.name] for g in Group.objects.all().order_by('name')]

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id': 'first_name',
        'tabindex': '1',
    }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id': 'last_name',
        'tabindex': '2'
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'tabindex': '4'
    }))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'tabindex': '5'
    }))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id': 'username',
        'tabindex': '-1',
        'placeholder': 'Automatically generated suggestion...'
        }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'tabindex': '3'
    }))
    roles = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=ROLES, attrs={
        'class': 'form-control select2',
        'style': 'width:100%;',
        'multiple': 'multiple',
        'placeholder': 'Click on me to add a role'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'roles')
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def create_employee(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Get info from "both" forms
        # It appears as one form to the user on the .html page
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # Check to see both forms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            # Save User Form to Database
            user = user_form.save()

            # Hash the password
            user.set_password(user.password)
            # Update with Hashed password
            user.save()

            # Now we deal with the extra info!
            # Update roles membership
            roles = user_form.fields['roles']
            for role in roles:
                assign_role(user, role)
            user.save()

            # Can't commit yet because we still need to manipulate
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            # Set One to One relationship between
            # UserForm and UserProfileInfoForm
            profile.user = user

            # Now save model
            profile.save()

            # Registration Successful!
            registered = True

        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        # Was not an HTTP post so we just render the forms as blank.
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # This is the render and context dictionary to feed
    # back to the modal_create_user.html file page.
    return render(request, 'pages/create_employee.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        'registered': registered
    })
```

**EDIT WITH TRACEBACK:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/employee/create

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'imagekit',
 'rolepermissions',
 'django_messages',
 'taggit',
 'dispatch']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'dispatch.activeuser_middleware.ActiveUserMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jboucher/openroad/openroad/dispatch/views.py" in create_employee
  67.             for role in roles:

Exception Type: TypeError at /employee/create
Exception Value: 'CharField' object is not iterable
```

**NEWEST EDIT:
Now it assigns every single role no matter what is selected.**

```
# Now we deal with the extra info!
            # Update roles membership
            roles = user_form.fields['roles'].choices
            for role in roles:
                print('%s assigned to %s', role, user)
                assign_role(user, role[1])
            user.save()
```

Comment: post the trackback also

Comment: Added traceback to original post

Comment: roles is a char field. Why are you trying to iterate over it? Do u want to iterate over every char ?

Comment: because the field is passing the values like this: driver, system_admin, etc...  I need to be able to assign one at a time in the assign_roles operator. I tried changing my form.y but I can't seem to get it right, and pass all the attrs I need for my template.

Comment: convert roles to string (if it is not string already) then use roles.split(',') which  will give you a list like [driver, system_admin, ....]. Now you can iterate over it using your for loop

Comment: Tried that before. Got CharField has no attribute split().

Comment: use print(type(roles)) if its not string then convert into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define roles here:

```
roles = user_form.fields['roles']
```

This boils down to:

> Give me the field instance named 'roles'

You probably were looking for:

```
roles = user_form.cleaned_data['roles']
```

But you have defined the roles as a `CharField`, with a widget that returns multiple values. So you will need to fix your form definition as well, using a `MultipleChoiceField`.

Finally, I wonder if you really need to define all those fields. `ModelForm` can generate form fields from the model definition and does a pretty a good job at it. So you should only focus on the fields it does **not** do correctly.

Comment: Had to modify i slightly, but got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues here.

Firstly, the form `fields` dict contains the field objects themselves. It does not contain the *data* that was entered into those fields; that is present in the form `cleaned_data` dict.

Secondly, you are using the wrong field type. A CharField, as the name implies, is for strings of characters. But you want a list of choices, from which the user can select many - so you should use a [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).

Comment: Tried using the cleaned_data tag, and all I got was the role_id. Used fields['roles'].choices instead but now its adding every group. Added edit to original post above.